# Eclipse: how to show only what is printed in console.log

Tags: eclipse, console

I would like to know if there is any way for Eclipse to show in the console only what I want to print through "System.out.print".

For further clarification, what I am trying to do is a test through Appium, where I print texts as the test passes, and I only want to see that, not everything that a test shows in the console.
Is this possible?

Comment: https://www.headspin.io/blog/anatomy-of-logging-in-appium

Comment: Nothing described in that article solves the problem I have